# Zoom an image view on double click on it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to show a *zoom in* and *zoom out* effect on an `ImageView`, when clicking it.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not found better solution on web.. :(

Comment: Did you try anything? Show us some code or *something*.

Comment: I saw about imageview on scrollview. But its not working for me.. @woz

Comment: Why not? Show the code and any error messages.

Comment: Please read [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [sscce.org](http://sscce.org).  Right now your question looks like you haven't put much if any effort into solving it yourself.  Can you include some code?

Comment: There is a zooming property is there for a scroll view... Search for UIScrollView class reference and you will get some good understanding there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to add the image view as a subview of a UIScrollView. You could install a UITapGestureRecognizer on the scroll view and set the numberOfTapsRequired property to 2. In the callback method of the gesture recognizer, just set the zoomScale property of the scroll view to your desired zoom amount. Don't forget to set maximumZoomScale and minimumZoomScale on the scroll view as well.